# How to avoid overfitting in the given Convnet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a CNN network for sentence classification; I am trying to follow the architecture proposed in the [paper](http://emnlp2014.org/papers/pdf/EMNLP2014181.pdf). I am using Keras (with tensor-flow) for that. The following is the summary of my model:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)             (None, 56)            0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)            (None, 56, 300)       6510000                                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)              (None, 56, 300)       0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_10 (Conv1D)               (None, 54, 100)       90100                                        
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_11 (Conv1D)               (None, 53, 100)       120100                                       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_12 (Conv1D)               (None, 52, 100)       150100                                       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_10 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 27, 100)       0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_11 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 26, 100)       0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_12 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 26, 100)       0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)             (None, 2700)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_11 (Flatten)             (None, 2600)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)             (None, 2600)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)      (None, 7900)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)              (None, 7900)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                  (None, 50)            395050                                       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                  (None, 5)             255                                          
====================================================================================================
Total params: 7,265,605.0
Trainable params: 7,265,605.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
```

With the given architecture I am experiencing serious overfitting. The following are my results:
[image]

I am unable to understand what is the reason for the overfitting please suggest me some changes to the architecture for avoiding that. If you need some more information then please let me know.

Source code:

```
if model_type in ['CNN-non-static', 'CNN-static']:
    embedding_wts = train_word2vec( np.vstack((x_train, x_test, x_valid)), 
                                    ind_to_wrd, num_features = embedding_dim)
    if model_type == 'CNN-static':
        x_train = embedding_wts[0][x_train]
        x_test  = embedding_wts[0][x_test]
        x_valid = embedding_wts[0][x_valid]

elif model_type == 'CNN-rand':
    embedding_wts = None

else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown model type")

batch_size   = 50
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]
num_filters  = 75
dropout_prob = (0.5, 0.8)
hidden_dims  = 50

l2_reg = 0.3

# Deciding dimension of input based on the model
input_shape = (max_sent_len, embedding_dim) if model_type == "CNN-static" else (max_sent_len,)
model_input = Input(shape = input_shape)

# Static model do not have embedding layer
if model_type == "CNN-static":
    z = Dropout(dropout_prob[0])(model_input)
else:
    z = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length = max_sent_len, name="embedding")(model_input)
    z = Dropout(dropout_prob[0])(z)

# Convolution layers
z1 = Conv1D(    filters=num_filters, kernel_size=3, 
                padding="valid", activation="relu", 
                strides=1)(z)
z1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(z1)
z1 = Flatten()(z1)

z2 = Conv1D(    filters=num_filters, kernel_size=4, 
                padding="valid", activation="relu", 
                strides=1)(z)
z2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(z2)
z2 = Flatten()(z2)

z3 = Conv1D(    filters=num_filters, kernel_size=5, 
                padding="valid", activation="relu",
                strides=1)(z)
z3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(z3)
z3 = Flatten()(z3)

# Concatenate the output of all convolution layers
z = Concatenate()([z1, z2, z3])
z = Dropout(dropout_prob[1])(z)

# Dense(64, input_dim=64, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))

z = Dense(hidden_dims, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(z)
model_output = Dense(N_category, activation="sigmoid")(z)

model = Model(model_input, model_output)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1, decay=0.005), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```

Comment: How large is the training corpus? how many total weights do you have in your network? Just looking at the epics it seems to me that, unless you ran it for a year or you have access to some cool supercomputer you do not have enough data.

Comment: I am using stanford sentiment tree bank dataset. Training set, test set and validation set sizes are : 8544, 2210, 1101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From model summary looks like you are working on multi-class problem with 5 output classes. For multi-class setting `softmax` is good fit instead of `sigmoid`. I guess this is the major reason for very poor performance. On multi-class problem if you set network with sigmoid and categorical_crossentropy then during trainin by simply predicting all class to 1 could achieve 100% training accuracy, but this assumption fails badly on test data.

And if you are working with binary classification problem then binary_crossentropy is good choice for loss function.

Few other useful suggestions, may be helpful, but it's all up to your modeling assumptions.

- I guess you are following similar kind of approach explained in [example](https://github.com/alexander-rakhlin/CNN-for-Sentence-Classification-in-Keras/blob/master/sentiment_cnn.py). But If your training data is small the best practice is to use pretrained word embedding and allow fine tuning. You can find pretrained embedding initialization example [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py). But allow fine tuning by setting `trainable=True` in embedding layer.
- In paper mentioned, he pulls single feature from each filter,`pool_size = max_sent_len-filter_size+1`. This will extract only single important feature from whole sentence. This setting will allow you to reduce your model complexity. Very good explained in Reference: [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/)
- In same approach they used only single dense layer, you can remove your one hidden dense layer. Number of output features are quit small from pulling layer(will be equal to number of filters, each filter will only output one feature)

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the model in depth I would say that you should try to not train the embedding and reuse one of the downloadable matrix. Even if you cut that, you still have almost 10 times as many parameters as you have data points, So the model is bound to be overfitting.

It should be the other way around. for 800k parameters you should have 8M data points.

If you look at the graph, the validation loos goes down on the first (few) epoch and then goes up which is another indication of not having enough data.

Comment: I have added my source code. Based on your suggestions I tried different things like adding l2 regularization. Now, although loss is not increasing as shown in the graph but still the results are not satisfactory

Comment: Are you learning the embeddings? You can download pretrained embeddings here https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ . You could also try to use transfer learning to train the 3 convolutions on some other classification dataset like http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume5/lewis04a/lyrl2004_rcv1v2_README.htm, then set them as not trainable and only train the upper layer for your specific problem